# Multiplication, division. What is wrong?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

Simple operations. Calculate time delay.

```
const unsigned long C1 = 30 * 1000;
const unsigned long C2 = (300 * 1000)/C1; // must be = 10

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Serial.println("\n-------");
  Serial.print("C1 = "); Serial.println(C1);
  Serial.print("C2 = "); Serial.println(C2);

  unsigned long V1 = (300 * 1000)/C1;   // must be = 10
  Serial.print("V1 = "); Serial.println(V1);

  long V2 = (300 * 1000)/30000; // must be = 10
  Serial.print("V2 = "); Serial.println(V2);

  int V3 = (300 * 1000)/30000; // must be = 10
  Serial.print("V3 = "); Serial.println(V3);
}

void loop() {
}
```

Arduino UNO printed in monitor console:

- C1 = 30000   (ok)
- C2 = 143164  (must be = 10)
- V1 = 143164  (must be = 10)
- V2 = 0       (must be = 10)
- V3 = 0       (must be = 10)

What is wrong?

Comment: Hack `long V2 = (300 * 1000UL)/30000;` printed `10`

Answer (score 3):

**300 * 1000** is expected to give **30'0000**, or **0x493E0** in hexadecimal.
But when you write **(300 * 1000)**, the Arduino uses **16 bits signed integer arithmetic**, so the result is truncated to **0x93E0** (or -27680 in decimal).

When you then divide by an unsigned long, the result is converted to unsigned long and this gives **0xFFFF'93E0** or **4'294'939'616** in decimal.

Divide by 30'000 and you get **143'164**.

For **V2** it is the same: (300 * 1000) = -27680 in 16 bit signed arithmetic and -27'680 / 30'000 gives **0**.